# JavaFX realidade ou apenas especulação?

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho experiência em Swing de 8 anos, mas a algum tempo andei lendo que com o Java 9 o Swing será totalmente abandonado pela Oracle. Agora surgiu a necessidade de eu desenvolver um sistema Desktop para um cliente e me veio algumas dúvidas.

Minhas dúvida são as seguintes:

1. A JVM deixará de rodar os programas desenvolvidos em Swing/AWT ?
2. A JDK irá possuir apenas o Toolkit para desenvolvimento JavaFX ?
3. O JavaFX realmente é ideal para desenvolvimento Desktop visto que o grande feeling dele eh RIA?

Enfim, será mesmo o fim do Swing/AWT ?

Comment: Pergunta interessante. Mas quanto a primeira pergunta, acho que isso não acontece, o maximo que creio que vá acontecer é aqueles avisos de que está depreciado na hora de desenvolver.

Comment: [Dê uma olhada aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5828734/4056678).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1-Naturalmente não, a JVM depende da que o utilizador tiver instalada, provavelmente quando sair o 9 deve conseguir executar também o 8, portanto a JVM não vai ser problema vai garantidamente haver forma de executar programas de versões anteriores.

2-Provavelmente no entanto acredito que vá existir bibliotecas externas para o Swing/AWT, não será nada oficial mas deve funcionar da mesma forma não tendo nenhuma melhoria.

3-JavaFX supera em muitos pontos o Swing, o javaFX possui uma API bem mais simples além de ser mais customizavél com as css mas o swing não fica muita atrás mas como neste momento o javaFX é possui grandes melhorias não faz sentido continuar com a "pior".